# Pytesseract whitelist a set of strings

Tags: python, ocr, tesseract, python-tesseract

I am trying to detect text from a report safed as image. The report always has the same structure.

e.g.
See picture below

[image]

Example found by google.

The actual report contains mostly internal abbreviations from the aviation industry which are not recognized correctly by Pytesseract.

The program must recognize only CC, C1, ..., Parameter Names (list of Strings) + numbers. So basicly im look for a way to whitelist a couple of strings and all numbers. Is this possibe to specify in Pytesseract?
So far I have only found tessedit_char_whitelist, which unfortunately does not help me.

What i have done so far:

```
import cv2
import pytesseract as pt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

filename = 'Rep15_4.jpg'
img = cv2.imread(filename)


# best resutls!!!
#config = r'--oem 1 --psm 4'
# or
#config = r'--oem 1 --psm 6'
# or 
#config = r'--oem 3 --psm 4'

config = r'--oem 3 --psm 4'
text = pt.image_to_string(img, config = config)
```

For config i have tried all options for oem and psm. On top i tried to manipulate the image with cv2 -> cvtColor, GaussianBlur, threshold. Most problematic are the 0 values.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: it could help if you post an example image without a black rectangle as it causes a problem with image analysis/preprocessing  + full expected output and code you already use.

Comment: Sure, i have uploaded another image and the code i have written.

Comment: @nathancy: why you are posting a bunch of not relevant links to all tesseract related SO post?

Comment: @Adrian: you will need to retrain tesseract for zero character (at least)

Comment: @user898678 they are relevant, to perform OCR on the images, you can't directly throw it into tesseract. Some preprocessing has to be done either to remove noise, borders, or manipulate the characters into a format where the OCR libraries can identify them